# Is there combined version of jquery and jquery UI files and hosted by google?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox

Is there any jquery files which is combined of all these files below and hosted from google ?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Files : Jquery and Jquery ui and Fancybox.

Comment: these javascript libraries are all separate projects, and can't be in one file, theoretically you can copy and paste in one .js file, but you'd better use them separately, or you can turn on .js caching if you are using any kind of CMS

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no combined files.  It really doesn't matter either, because only the the initial download from ANY website using Google's CDN will allow the browser to cache the file.  Combining the files has no significant performance increase due to the browser cache.

Comment: does that mean the files are cached and used across different websites as the scripts com from the same sauce?